# Is there any way to enable intellisense for notepad++, HTML coding?

Tags: html, notepad++

Is there any way to enable intellisense for notepad++?

I have heard that the closest thing is a plugin called fingertext, but I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, there is one in NP++ v6.6.8 and it is disabled by default. To enable it, in your menu bar navigate to:

> 1. Settings
> 2. Preferences
> 3. Auto-completion
> 4. Tick the *"Enable auto-completion on each input"*
> 5. Close