# Notepad++ intellisense for user-defined functions

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, notepad++

I understand that I can enable auto-completion in Notepad++ by going to "*Settings -> Preferences -> Backup/Auto-completion*". For example with Python, the auto-completion only works for a set of pre-defined functions according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165017/is-there-any-way-to-enable-intellisense-for-notepad-html-coding).

Does anyone know how to make intellisense in Notepad++ for the functions and methods that I define? I'm no expert in this but I was thinking, surely there must be a way that Notepad++ can automatically detect function definition in the code, and add those functions to its intellisense database or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable auto complete support in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893761/how-can-i-enable-auto-complete-support-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the relative [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Auto_Completion).
Have a look at the files in `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\plugins\APIs`.

Comment: Thanks Alain1405. What that documentation seems to show is how to add another function to the database. What I was rather looking for is the ability to detect a function definition automatically, and automatically add it to a (perhaps temporary) database, available for auto-completion and calltip. Do you know what I mean? Obviously, I don't want to have to manually add a function to the auto-completion definition files every time I define a new function in my source code.

Comment: I strongly doubt that what you ask it exist. I also strongly doubt that Notepad++ can do any kind of code analysis, so how can it recognize a function definition? As far as I know there isn't any plugin for this. Try with Vim with omnicomplete plugin. Other good IDE's for python are emacs, Komodo, NetBeans, PyDev or WingIDE. Source here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah I too doubted that such things existed, that's really what I was asking.