# In Notepad++, is there a way can I display a customizable list of popup "hint" descriptions for functions as they are typed?

Tags: notepad++

For Example, I could use this feature such that when I type "SUM"
it would display "SUM(number1,[number2], ...)" in  a popup alongside my text.
Inspiration for my question comes from excel's function autocomplete.
Thanks
~MM

From what I have attempted, the UDL and Function List Features do not have built in descriptions

Comment: Does [this info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16361331/7644018) help?